# Canvas Draw Line With Two Color At the Same Point

Tags: javascript, canvas

The Code Is Like Below:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
context.stroke();
```

And Here is the result:
I don't want the dash Line,
How To cover the red Line totally?
[image]

Comment: This is actually due to antialiasing of the lines, which is quite hard to get rid of in this example. A basic solution would just be doing `context.lineWidth = 12;` on the second line. Another is to draw your own lines several times on coordinates `x+.5,y+.5`